# Get the minimum time from multiple rows

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    invlod.lodnum, 
    dlytrn.trndte
FROM  
    invlod
INNER JOIN
    dlytrn ON invlod.lodnum = dlytrn.lodnum
WHERE
    invlod.stoloc = (@stoloc) 
    AND dlytrn.actcod = 'PALPCK' 
    AND dlytrn.oprcod = 'PCK'
ORDER BY 
    dlytrn.trndte
```

Resulting output:

```
00100370000510204922    1/24/2019 7:28:26 AM    
00100370000510204922    1/24/2019 7:28:44 AM    
00100370000510204939    1/24/2019 7:28:57 AM    
00100370000510204939    1/24/2019 7:29:12 AM    
00100370008030047708    1/24/2019 7:37:01 AM    
00100370008030047708    1/24/2019 7:37:01 AM
```

I need unique (minimum) time stamps. If there are duplicates, I want just one output.

Comment: Mininum time for an invoice ? just use min(time) and group by invoice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `group by` like this:

```
select invlod.lodnum, min(dlytrn.trndte) as trndte
from invlod
inner join dlytrn on invlod.lodnum = dlytrn.lodnum
where invlod.stoloc = (@stoloc) and dlytrn.actcod= 'PALPCK' and dlytrn.oprcod = 'PCK'
group by invlod.lodnum
order by trndte
```

Comment: This is not giving me the time output in ascending order. I am not being able to add     order by dlytrn.trndte

Answer (score 1):

### In oracle

```
Select distinct 
invlod.lodnum, 
 min ( dlytrn.trndte) over ( partition by invlod.lodnum) min_trndte
FROM invlod
inner join dlytrn on invlod.lodnum = dlytrn.lodnum
where invlod.stoloc = (@stoloc) and dlytrn.actcod= 'PALPCK' and dlytrn.oprcod = 'PCK'
Order by dlytrn.trndte
```